# Printing various pdf files with print dialog visible from asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, printing

I am creating pdf files in an asp.net project that is being stored on the server in a folder. When a user wants to print this file, I need the user to specify which printer among all the label printers on the network since it may contain numeral laser printers as well. **I have tried creating a print process but this send the pdf file straight to the default printer. is there any way to display the print dialog so that users can select the required printer?**

```
            printjob.StartInfo.FileName = pdfFileName;<br/>
            printjob.StartInfo.Verb = "Print";<br/>
            printjob.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;<br/>
            printjob.StartInfo.WindowStyle =         System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
            PrinterSettings setting = new PrinterSettings();<br/>
            printjob.Start();
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved by Spire.pdf.dll reference.
To install this Open package manager console and type Install-Package Spire.pdf. this will install spire.pdf. Now the following code will help you print the pdf files.

```
        PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument();
        doc.LoadFromFile("D:\\sample.pdf");

        //Use the default printer to print all the pages
        //doc.PrintDocument.Print();

        //Set the printer and select the pages you want to print

        PrintDialog dialogPrint = new PrintDialog();
        dialogPrint.AllowPrintToFile = true;
        dialogPrint.AllowSomePages = true;
        dialogPrint.PrinterSettings.MinimumPage = 1;
        dialogPrint.PrinterSettings.MaximumPage = doc.Pages.Count;
        dialogPrint.PrinterSettings.FromPage = 1;
        dialogPrint.PrinterSettings.ToPage = doc.Pages.Count;

        if (dialogPrint.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            doc.PrintFromPage = dialogPrint.PrinterSettings.FromPage;
            doc.PrintToPage = dialogPrint.PrinterSettings.ToPage;
            doc.PrinterName = dialogPrint.PrinterSettings.PrinterName;

            PrintDocument printDoc = doc.PrintDocument;
            dialogPrint.Document = printDoc;
            printDoc.Print();
        }
```